# Debugging a connection problem between Linux and monitor

Tags: linux, multi-monitor

I have two laptops, and I use a KVM (USB-C to the KVM, then HDMI from KVM to monitor) to connect them to a single monitor. One of the laptops is dual boot Linux/windows. The issue I am having is that the dual boot laptop, when booted into Linux, does not seem to recognize the monitor. To make this more specific:

- Both laptops have exactly the same Linux distro (NixOS 21.05, from the same config file)
- The non-dual-boot laptop works with the KVM
- The dual boot laptop works with the KVM, from windows but not from linux.

When using linux on the dual boot laptop, `xrandr` does not show the monitor.

There are two USB-C ports on the dual-boot laptop - one thunderbolt and the other displayport via USB-C. When in Windows, oddly only the displayport via USB-C port works - the monitor is not detected if the KVM is connected to the thunderbolt port.

After typing `xrandr` a few times and observing that the monitor wasn't showing up, I realized I had reached the limits of my linux skills when it comes to figuring out why not. Could anyone give me any advice?

Thanks in advance, and after the event.

Comment: Displayport via USB-C uses "alternate mode" on USB-C. This is not going to work on Linux out-of-the-box, because there are no standard drivers. It's even worse with Thunderbolt. You'll be lucky to get this to work at all with your hardware, and it'll need a lot of googling with PCI ids, data sheets, etc.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks, what you say makes sense. The monitor is working via the thunderbolt port on my other laptop, though, and although I've had that for longer I don't recall having done anything too special to get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone with the same problem - I solved this by following the instructions here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Thunderbolt to add a udev rule to enable my thunderbolt port - see directly below:

Users who just want to connect any device without any sort of manual work can create a udev rule as in 99-removable.rules:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-removable.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="thunderbolt", ATTR{authorized}=="0", ATTR{authorized}="1"
```

Comment: Maybe add the details from the link to the answer? There doesn't seem to be too much to copy and paste.